My docker compose does not get my env variable
this is my docker compose file:
services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      - MY_MESSAGE=Hello, World!
    command: ["sh", "-c", "echo $MY_MESSAGE"]
    container_name: alpine-env-container

and i have warning like this 
WARN[0000] The "MY_MESSAGE" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
and my env MY_MESSAGE is empty
i want to use env variable in command in docker compose

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Shouldn't your environment variable assignment should be like this:

MY_MESSAGE="Hello, World!"


@MohsinMurad It definitely shouldn't: Compose doesn't treat those double quotes specially, so they'll become part of the variable's text.

In the compose file:
command: ["sh", "-c", "echo $MY_MESSAGE"]

Will expand $MY_MESSAGE by compose itself, not by the shell inside the container. So you can define the variable on the host, or in a .env file for that to be defined for compose.
Or if you want to expand the variable inside of the container, you need to escape the variable with a second $:
command: ["sh", "-c", "echo $$MY_MESSAGE"]

